# Manga (called "Blue"?): robot merges with boy after the kid gets beaten to death, new body is that of an adult man

Tags: story-identification, manga

Manga is about a boy in outer space and a weird robot. The kid gets beaten close to death and the robot decides to merge with the boy to save his life they become a new being (Cyborg) and for some reason the new body is of an adult man.

I thought it was called *Blue* but can't find it online.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already but could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when would it have been published, any recollection of the covers?

Answer (score 5):

That might be *Cyber Blue* (1988), albeit with some slightly mistaken memories.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/9252/Cyber_Blue):

> **We are in year 2035 on the Tinos planet**, colonized 300 years before by some earthlings. With only half of Earth's oxygen concentration and with cold arctic conditions over most of Tinos, the human beings are forced to wear a life support apparatus that supplies the oxygen necessary for survival. The black market in such apparatuses is a flourishing business in the criminal world of Junk City.
>
> **Blue, the protagonist**, is in desperate need of a life support system after being mugged, but an unscrupulous bunch of criminals cheat him of his money and leave him with an outdated model with an old AI. He is tricked by the head of the police, Weiser, into a committing murder, and **is then killed himself. The AI, called Fatso, decides to save his life, and gives him a new artificial body** filled with extraordinary strength and the cumulative knowledge of their combined three hundred and seventeen years. The resurrected Blue decides to get revenge and protect all those suffering under the tyranny of Weiser.

As I said, some of the matching parts still differ a bit from your recollection:

- there is "Blue" in the title alright, and the main character is named Blue;
- action does take place in space (the planet Tinos);
- Blue is a teenager. 17 years old, so not yet a man, but (to me) he doesn't really look like a kid either, although various characters call him "brat" or "boy". See his pre-transform self below:

[image: Merchant prompts Blue into buying the machine]

- Blue takes a beating, but the "close to death" (well, dead) actually happens due to dozens of rounds being fired at him, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRAcF.jpg) (**warning NSFW character gets gunned down**)
- the robot (an outdated AI called "Fatso", who uses the f-word a lot) fuses with the protagonist indeed...

  [image: robot performs surgery on Blue]
- ... but the "New Man", [while being way broader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZHdO.jpg) (**warning NSFW naked guy**), still doesn't look much older, to me at least. Compare the two next to each other in the picture below. The new Blue does have cyborg abilities (his eyes have some kind of auto-aim, etc).

  [image: side-by-side comparison of before and after rebirth]

---

Found by browsing MyAnimeList for manga titles including "blue" ([link to list](https://myanimelist.net/manga.php?q=blue)). *Cyber Blue* was on the second page, I'm not sure how it's sorted.

Comment: Yes this the one thank you very much 